# How do I add a custom context menu for 'git gui' in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, git, context-menu

What I want to achieve is to get a "Git GUI here" item in the context menu of Nautilus (file manager). It should this easy job I would do in a terminal:

```
cd "path/to/current/folder"
git gui # <-- this pops up a GUI for Git in a new window
```

I'm using [Nautilus Actions Configurator](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/) application to achieve this as shown below.

[image]

It does *show* the custom context menu, yet I would have expected it to also *work* this way, but it doesn't. Upon hitting my button it just opens Git GUI without actually run in the working directory of Nautilus is in.

What am I doing wrong about this current working directory?

Comment: @gertvdijk when I leave path empty, item doesn't appear at all

Comment: @gertvdijk ok did it. But it opens git gui. Not in current dir.

Comment: @gertvdijk oh. I kinda got it. It opens git in parent folder. NOt in current

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to markup your working directory. This is how I would do it:

Path: `/usr/bin/git`

Parameters: `gui`

Working directory: `%d/%b`

This will use the current directory, then the basename of the directory selected.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work on Linux Mint with Cinnamon as I cannot install nautilus-actions. Also the link the OP mentioned is outdated.